# How to do take and skip functionality in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM Table
OFFSET 10 rows           
FETCH NEXT 15 rows only;
```

Error is:Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.

Comment: `OFFSET` requires an `ORDER BY`; you're missing one.

Comment: [SELECT - ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

you can read this article
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/

and by the way your select missing an order by
for example like this

```
    SELECT
product_name,
list_price FROM production.products ORDER BY    list_price,    product_name  OFFSET 10 ROWS;
```